# Bookdown in-chapter formatting: different pages per paragraph

Tags: r, bookdown

We - bookdown noobs - are making a bookdown with a lot of text per paragraph (using the [minimal bookdown](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-minimal) as a template, we only added new Rmd files from here). At the moment, one has to scroll a long time before reaching the end of a chapter, because we have many paragraphs per chapter and all paragraphs are pasted on **1 page**. In the bookdown example however, each paragraph appears on a **separate page**. I have looked in the code of the example and tried to copy some index code to ours, but that still pastes everything to one page when knitting to html.

How can we make sure each paragraph (e.g, 3.1, 3.2) appears on a separate page, instead of all paragraphs appearing on the same page (chapter 3 in its entirety)?

This is our index.Rmd code (don't know whether of any use):

```
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
    bookdown::gitbook: default
```

R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12); Bookdown version 0.18

Thanks very much in advance. I am a Latex/Pandoc noob so this may be a very stupid question.

Comment: Do you have a git repository where we can see the paragraphs? If you use one h1 header (# Header 1) per RMD file (chapter) and then separate each paragraph with a h2 header (## Header 2), I think it should work.

Comment: https://github.com/eduardklap/braindev-labmanual
I don't think it has to do with the headers. We do have one # header 1 per .rmd file, but I suspect it has to do with some settings of the book that we don't know about. I just don't know which one

Comment: Is it a priveate repository because I have no access to it.

Comment: You should have access now!

Comment: There is an error in your code, because you use three times the chunk name "pressure". Please change that. If you do, you get the following result: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kWZtm0KOzO60xcG_q6vCDCz4BPLMKpYv
Do you expect that? In my opinion it´s exactly what you asked for, or? Did you use `bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd")`?